# Weka in my Java code - Text categorization using StringToWordVector seems not to work

Tags: java, text, weka, categorization

I'm new to text categorization, I'm trying to use weka to build a decision tree based on single terms and n-grams with associated tf-idf, to classify some text in positive or negative class, considering the opinion contained in it. It's a particular task of text categorization, which is usually referred to as 'Sentiment classification'.
So I've found a lot of interesting guides on the topic.
I'm trying to use J48 on a labeled training set, using a StringToWordVector filter, using tf-idf transform, and using a NGramWordTokenizer to tokenize the input documents of the training set corpus.

```
public class TextIndexer {

public static final int TFIDF=1;
public static final int TF=2;
public static final int BOW=3;

private static String sourceDirectory;
private static Instances inputInstances;
private static WordTokenizer singleWordTokenizer;
private static NGramTokenizer nGramTokenizer;
private static StringToWordVector wv;
private static boolean ngram;
private static int minOccSingleWords;
private static int minOccNGrams;

public TextIndexer (String fileDir) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileDir));
    ArffReader arff = new ArffReader(reader);

    inputInstances = arff.getData();

    reader.close();
    minOccSingleWords=minOccNGrams=2;
    ngram=false;
    tdl=new TextDirectoryLoader();
    wv=new StringToWordVector();
    singleWordTokenizer = new WordTokenizer();

    defaultConfig();
    }

private static final void defaultConfig() {
    singleWordTokenizer.setDelimiters("\\W");
    wv.setDoNotOperateOnPerClassBasis(true);
    wv.setUseStoplist(false);
    wv.setLowerCaseTokens(true);
    wv.setWordsToKeep(1000000);
    wv.setIDFTransform(true);
}
```

So in TextIndexer I've methods to set the minimum number of occurrences, the weight to use for features, to eventually enable ngrams, etc.

I call TextIndexer in my main class, which builds a J48 based on the filtered Instances, using method toWordVector:

```
public  Instances toWordVector() throws NullPointerException {
    try {
        wv.setInputFormat(inputInstances);
        System.out.println(inputInstances.numInstances());
        wv.setTokenizer(singleWordTokenizer);
        wv.setMinTermFreq(minOccSingleWords);
        Instances i = Filter.useFilter(inputInstances, wv);
        System.out.println(i);
            //i.setClass(i.attribute("class"));

        if(ngram) {
            wv.setInputFormat(inputInstances);
            wv.setTokenizer(nGramTokenizer);
            wv.setMinTermFreq(minOccNGrams);
            Instances i2 = Filter.useFilter(inputInstances, wv);
            i2.deleteAttributeAt(0);
            for(int ie=0;ie<i2.numAttributes();ie++)
            System.out.println(i2.attribute(ie));
            i= Instances.mergeInstances(i, i2);
        }

        i.setClassIndex(0);
        return i;


    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new NullPointerException("Cannot find instances from selected source file");
    }

}
```

That's my main class code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{   

    try {
        TextIndexer ti = new TextIndexer("C:/.../TRAINING SET WEKA/TRAIN.arff");

        ti.setTokensWeight(ti.TFIDF);
        ti.enableNGrams(2,3);

        J48 tree = new J48();
        Instances in=ti.toWordVector();

        tree.buildClassifier(in);
```

Well, my classifier is built. 
Now, I'm trying to use it to classify some text, so I use 10 text(5 positive, 5 negative) kept from the training set, creating an arff file with two attributes: document(type string) and class(positive or negative), setting the data with class "?".

When I try to use classifyInstance(Instance i), the result is always 0.0(or positive). That's the code of classifying, used in my main class:

```
Instances unlabeled = new Instances(new BufferedReader(
                new FileReader("C:/Users/Honestus_/Desktop/TRAINING SET WEKA/TEST.arff")));
// set class attribute
unlabeled.setClassIndex(unlabeled.numAttributes() - 1);
// create copy
Instances labeled = new Instances(unlabeled);
// label instances
for (int i = 0; i < unlabeled.numInstances(); i++) {
double clsLabel = tree.classifyInstance(unlabeled.instance(i));
labeled.instance(i).setClassValue(clsLabel);
}
```

As you can see, this part of code is the same as [Using Weka in your java code](https://weka.wikispaces.com/Classification-Train/test%20set#Classification-Classifying%20instances). What's wrong? I've tried to use FilteredClassifier too, but it makes no difference. 
I've read some similar problems, and the answers talked about some error in the training set. I'm using the training set by: [multi-domain sentiment](http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~mdredze/datasets/sentiment/), using 1000 positive and 1000 negative reviews from the "apparel" category.

I hope my question is pretty clear, thanks!